# Generic Interface class signature

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get inheritance, I just don't get why this interface implements itself?

Also, please could you explain what the emboldened part does? Why can I not just say where T is IIdentifiableEntity, instead of all those comma separated sections?

```
public interface IDataRepository<T> : IDataRepository
        **where T : class, IIdentifiableEntity, new()**
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Theres more than one question here.. I'll tackle them one by one:

> Why this interface implements itself?

It doesn't. There is two types here .. one generic .. one non-generic. Why does it implement the non-generic one? Who knows .. we need to see the entire data layer to understand that. Its important to realize they are two types though.

> Why can I not just say where T is IIdentifiableEntity

Again, this depends on your use case. `class` enforces a reference type as the generic parameter. So, you will not be able to create an instance of `IDataRepository<int>`. This makes sense in a data layer.. as you generally want to persist entire objects/graphs and they are generally reference types. `new()` allows you to use `var x = new T()` in your generic type. Without it, you will get a compiler error if you try to instantiate an instance of your generic type parameter.

Answer (score 1):

It is often useful to define interfaces either for generic collection classes, or for the generic classes that represent items in the collection. The preference for generic classes is to use generic interfaces, such as IComparable rather than IComparable, in order to avoid boxing and unboxing operations on value types. The .NET Framework class library defines several generic interfaces for use with the collection classes in the System.Collections.Generic namespace.
When an interface is specified as a constraint on a type parameter, only types that implement the interface can be used. The following code example shows a SortedList class that derives from the GenericList class. For more information, see Introduction to Generics (C# Programming Guide). SortedList adds the constraint where T : IComparable. This enables the BubbleSort method in SortedList to use the generic CompareTo method on list elements. In this example, list elements are a simple class, Person, that implements IComparable. [Read](http://r4r.co.in/c1/01/tutorial/csharp/)

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 different interface `IDataRepository` which is general and `IDataRepository<T>` which is generic and restricted to class which has parameter less constructor and implemented `IIdentifiableEntity`. This is useful when your application is not only tied to `IDataRepository<T>` but you might have another generic interface like`IDataRepository<T> where T: IEntity`, and in some parts you want to treat them as one interface

For the next question if it only has `where T : IIdentifiableEntity` you can pass another `interface` or `struct` as T , but the architect wants developers to pass a `class` which has a parameter constructor as T